# Music App crashes frequently under iOS 5.0.1

Tags: ipod, music, crash

I'm running iOS 5.0.1, no jailbreaks, customizations etc.

Last night I synced some of my music (I manually manage my videos and music). Probably transferred about 5.8 GBs of music.

This morning, I try to open up the native music app to listen; it doesn't load a single list view, just crashes. I get to work and plug in my iPod and iTunes is able to read and play all my files, so it seems that the music app is the problem.

I'm wondering if anyone else had this problem or a potential fix that does not involve wiping all of my music off my iPod.

Comment: I assume that since you say you sync music, you don't subscribe to iTunes Match? I've seen similar issues, and wondered if it was due to iTunes Match or not.

Comment: Does the problem persist after you've rebooted the iPod?  Have you synched it with more than one iTunes library, and if so are they all the same version of iTunes (or at least close)?

Comment: I do not subscribe to iTunes Match. And I have rebooted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a software based issue. I would suggest backing up and restoring the device using [these](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4137) steps. I know you are wary about erasing all your music, but you can back it up to iTunes before doing this. Make sure you set it up as a new device so as not to transfer any old software back to the phone after the restore.

Comment: What if I don't have any of the music that's on the iPod on my work computer? The whole point of this question was to just prevent the crashing before I go on my long commute home :P

Comment: If you don't have any of the content on the computer you're restoring to, you can use a piece of software called [**Music Rescue**](http://www.kennettnet.co.uk/products/musicrescue/). This allows you to copy music from an iPod, iPhone or iPad to a computer.